# Using z-index between fixed positioned and relative positioned boxes

Tags: css, user-interface, navbar, z-index, footer

As I designed an UI/UX design for my website, I got a problem with using `z-index`-CSS-Property.

My main page is only a fixed picture and as you start scrolling, a white box is going to cover that main picture, but `navbar` is still above main content. When you continue scrolling and after you finish reading contents and you see `footer`, footer will cover `navbar` now. it means that `navbar` is above main picture and also main content. but it should NOT cover the footer:

```css
#footer {
    z-index: 1000;
}

#navbar {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

I defined `navbar` as LAST tag in my body and it's going to cover picture and main content correctly. but `footer` is LAST tag in MAIN CONTENT. because its going to be shown when you continue scrolling the main content. as you may be understood now, `navbar` covers / is above `footer`...

Any Idea to fix that?

If you think I can tell you more details, comment that

```css
html,body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}

#body {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-image: url(https://i.redd.it/u6mkl0evh2521.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
}

#scrollable_content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100vh;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        z-index: 9;
}

#scrollable_content #main_content {
        position: relative;
        width: 100vw;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background-color: #F4FFFF;
}

#navbar {
        display: flex;
        position: fixed;
        top: 22px;
        right: 3.5vw;
        left: 3.5vw;
        width: 93vw;
        height: 3rem;
        background-color: rgba(240, 254, 255, 0.3);
        backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        border: 1px solid #FFF5;
        border-radius: 20px;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        z-index: 10;
}

#footer {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: stretch;
        background-color: #09353E;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        z-index: 1000;
        position: relative;
}

#footer>h1 { color: #4BBACD }

::-webkit-scrollbar {
        height: 5px;
        width: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background-color: #F4FFFF;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: #ACE6EF;
        border-radius: 20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background-color: #09353E;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<main id="body"></main>
<article id="scrollable_content">
  <div id="main_content">
  
  <!-- content -->
  
  <h1>Main Content</h1>
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis fugiat nesciunt dolor eos incidunt animi consequatur nemo blanditiis, fuga tempora asperiores ipsum reprehenderit eius sed maxime repellat hic impedit similique doloribus assumenda a! Esse, distinctio? Vel, labore. Pariatur at ex ipsum deserunt vero sunt tempora officiis, quas odio a eveniet quia non doloribus nobis assumenda nemo quibusdam mollitia culpa? Animi pariatur consectetur quisquam provident delectus soluta aliquam est, eveniet quas facere tenetur. Voluptatem accusantium adipisci quod consectetur id deserunt quo? Et similique aliquam molestias omnis? Vitae hic impedit quidem, molestias nostrum accusantium labore. Natus impedit nemo, veritatis alias accusamus culpa.  

  <br>
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis fugiat nesciunt dolor eos incidunt animi consequatur nemo blanditiis, fuga tempora asperiores ipsum reprehenderit eius sed maxime repellat hic impedit similique doloribus assumenda a! Esse, distinctio? Vel, labore. Pariatur at ex ipsum deserunt vero sunt tempora officiis, quas odio a eveniet quia non doloribus nobis assumenda nemo quibusdam mollitia culpa? Animi pariatur consectetur quisquam provident delectus soluta aliquam est, eveniet quas facere tenetur. Voluptatem accusantium adipisci quod consectetur id deserunt quo? Et similique aliquam molestias omnis? Vitae hic impedit quidem, molestias nostrum accusantium labore. Natus impedit nemo, veritatis alias accusamus culpa. 
  
  <br>
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis fugiat nesciunt dolor eos incidunt animi consequatur nemo blanditiis, fuga tempora asperiores ipsum reprehenderit eius sed maxime repellat hic impedit similique doloribus assumenda a! Esse, distinctio? Vel, labore. Pariatur at ex ipsum deserunt vero sunt tempora officiis, quas odio a eveniet quia non doloribus nobis assumenda nemo quibusdam mollitia culpa? Animi pariatur consectetur quisquam provident delectus soluta aliquam est, eveniet quas facere tenetur. Voluptatem accusantium adipisci quod consectetur id deserunt quo? Et similique aliquam molestias omnis? Vitae hic impedit quidem, molestias nostrum accusantium labore. Natus impedit nemo, veritatis alias accusamus culpa.  
  
  </div>
  
  <footer id="footer">
  
  <h1>Footer goes here</h1>
  
  </footer>
</article>
<nav id="navbar"></nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your HTML. Post an interactive snippet instead of two incomplete CSS rules.

Comment: I did that @Dai, As you can see, navbar is above footer. its wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that needs to be done to achieve the desired result with your provided code is to remove `z-index: 9;` from `#scrollable_content`

```css
html,body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}

#body {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-image: url(https://i.redd.it/u6mkl0evh2521.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
}

#scrollable_content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100vh;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        /* z-index: 9; */ /* This is the simple solution */
}

#scrollable_content #main_content {
        position: relative;
        width: 100vw;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background-color: #F4FFFF;
}

#navbar {
        display: flex;
        position: fixed;
        top: 22px;
        right: 3.5vw;
        left: 3.5vw;
        width: 93vw;
        height: 3rem;
        background-color: rgba(240, 254, 255, 0.3);
        backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        border: 1px solid #FFF5;
        border-radius: 20px;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        z-index: 10;
}

#footer {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: stretch;
        background-color: #09353E;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        z-index: 1000;
        position: relative;
}

#footer>h1 { color: #4BBACD }

::-webkit-scrollbar {
        height: 5px;
        width: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background-color: #F4FFFF;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: #ACE6EF;
        border-radius: 20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background-color: #09353E;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<main id="body"></main>
<article id="scrollable_content">
  <div id="main_content">
  
  <!-- content -->
  
  <h1>Main Content</h1>
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis fugiat nesciunt dolor eos incidunt animi consequatur nemo blanditiis, fuga tempora asperiores ipsum reprehenderit eius sed maxime repellat hic impedit similique doloribus assumenda a! Esse, distinctio? Vel, labore. Pariatur at ex ipsum deserunt vero sunt tempora officiis, quas odio a eveniet quia non doloribus nobis assumenda nemo quibusdam mollitia culpa? Animi pariatur consectetur quisquam provident delectus soluta aliquam est, eveniet quas facere tenetur. Voluptatem accusantium adipisci quod consectetur id deserunt quo? Et similique aliquam molestias omnis? Vitae hic impedit quidem, molestias nostrum accusantium labore. Natus impedit nemo, veritatis alias accusamus culpa.  

  <br>
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis fugiat nesciunt dolor eos incidunt animi consequatur nemo blanditiis, fuga tempora asperiores ipsum reprehenderit eius sed maxime repellat hic impedit similique doloribus assumenda a! Esse, distinctio? Vel, labore. Pariatur at ex ipsum deserunt vero sunt tempora officiis, quas odio a eveniet quia non doloribus nobis assumenda nemo quibusdam mollitia culpa? Animi pariatur consectetur quisquam provident delectus soluta aliquam est, eveniet quas facere tenetur. Voluptatem accusantium adipisci quod consectetur id deserunt quo? Et similique aliquam molestias omnis? Vitae hic impedit quidem, molestias nostrum accusantium labore. Natus impedit nemo, veritatis alias accusamus culpa. 
  
  <br>
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis fugiat nesciunt dolor eos incidunt animi consequatur nemo blanditiis, fuga tempora asperiores ipsum reprehenderit eius sed maxime repellat hic impedit similique doloribus assumenda a! Esse, distinctio? Vel, labore. Pariatur at ex ipsum deserunt vero sunt tempora officiis, quas odio a eveniet quia non doloribus nobis assumenda nemo quibusdam mollitia culpa? Animi pariatur consectetur quisquam provident delectus soluta aliquam est, eveniet quas facere tenetur. Voluptatem accusantium adipisci quod consectetur id deserunt quo? Et similique aliquam molestias omnis? Vitae hic impedit quidem, molestias nostrum accusantium labore. Natus impedit nemo, veritatis alias accusamus culpa.  
  
  </div>
  
  <footer id="footer">
  
  <h1>Footer goes here</h1>
  
  </footer>
</article>
<nav id="navbar"></nav>

</body>
</html>
```

However, your markup has a lot of unnecessary CSS and bad semantic structure (I suggest reading the MDN article [Document and website structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Document_and_website_structure).)

In this example, I have provided a better semantic structure and commented out the unneeded CSS declarations. The only containers that need positioning are `nav` (to be fixed in place) and `footer` (relative only to be able to use z-index to overlay `nav`.) The only container that needs `z-index` is `footer`. The `#scrollable_content` container isn't needed.

I realized that the background color for `#main_content` wasn't being rendered in the top margin of the `h1`. I thought this was odd, especially since there isn't a collapsing margin from another element. I added 1px top padding to `#main_content` to fix this issue.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#body {
  /* display: block; */
  /* position: fixed; */
  /* top: 0; */
  /* right: 0; */
  /* left: 0; */
  /* bottom: 0; */
  /* width: 100vw; */
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://i.redd.it/u6mkl0evh2521.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#scrollable_content {
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* top: 100vh; */
  /* right: 0; */
  /* left: 0; */
  /* width: 100vw; */
  /* z-index: 9; */
}

#main_content {
  padding-block-start: 1px;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* width: 100vw; */
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F4FFFF;
  
}

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 22px;
  right: 3.5vw;
  left: 3.5vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  /* width: 93vw; */ /* use either 'right' or 'width' */
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: rgba(240, 254, 255, 0.3);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  border: 1px solid #FFF5;
  border-radius: 20px;
  /* z-index: 10; */
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: #09353E;
  /* width: 100vw; */
  /* height: 100vh; */
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* z-index: 1000; */
  z-index: 0;
}

#footer > h1 {
  color: #4BBACD;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #F4FFFF;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #ACE6EF;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #09353E;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

  <nav id="navbar"></nav>

  <div id="body"></div>
  <main id="main_content">
  <!-- <article id="scrollable_content"> -->

  <!-- content -->

  <h1>Main Content</h1>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis fugiat nesciunt dolor eos incidunt animi consequatur nemo blanditiis, fuga tempora asperiores ipsum reprehenderit eius sed maxime repellat hic impedit similique doloribus assumenda a! Esse, distinctio? Vel, labore. Pariatur at ex ipsum deserunt vero sunt tempora officiis, quas odio a eveniet quia non doloribus nobis assumenda nemo quibusdam mollitia culpa? Animi pariatur consectetur quisquam provident delectus soluta aliquam est, eveniet quas facere tenetur. Voluptatem accusantium adipisci quod consectetur id deserunt quo? Et similique aliquam molestias omnis? Vitae hic impedit quidem, molestias nostrum accusantium labore. Natus impedit nemo, veritatis alias accusamus culpa.  

  <br>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis fugiat nesciunt dolor eos incidunt animi consequatur nemo blanditiis, fuga tempora asperiores ipsum reprehenderit eius sed maxime repellat hic impedit similique doloribus assumenda a! Esse, distinctio? Vel, labore. Pariatur at ex ipsum deserunt vero sunt tempora officiis, quas odio a eveniet quia non doloribus nobis assumenda nemo quibusdam mollitia culpa? Animi pariatur consectetur quisquam provident delectus soluta aliquam est, eveniet quas facere tenetur. Voluptatem accusantium adipisci quod consectetur id deserunt quo? Et similique aliquam molestias omnis? Vitae hic impedit quidem, molestias nostrum accusantium labore. Natus impedit nemo, veritatis alias accusamus culpa. 

  <br>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis fugiat nesciunt dolor eos incidunt animi consequatur nemo blanditiis, fuga tempora asperiores ipsum reprehenderit eius sed maxime repellat hic impedit similique doloribus assumenda a! Esse, distinctio? Vel, labore. Pariatur at ex ipsum deserunt vero sunt tempora officiis, quas odio a eveniet quia non doloribus nobis assumenda nemo quibusdam mollitia culpa? Animi pariatur consectetur quisquam provident delectus soluta aliquam est, eveniet quas facere tenetur. Voluptatem accusantium adipisci quod consectetur id deserunt quo? Et similique aliquam molestias omnis? Vitae hic impedit quidem, molestias nostrum accusantium labore. Natus impedit nemo, veritatis alias accusamus culpa.  
  <!-- </article> -->
  </main>

  <footer id="footer">
    <h1>Footer goes here</h1>
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. In your second snippet, main image is also scrollable. I want to make it `fixed`. However, your first solution was useful for me, thanks

Comment: @MHSarmadi Whoops, I overlooked that. I have edited my answer to include `background-attachment: fixed`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `position: sticky` instead of fixed and relative?

```css
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  }

main {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: slateblue;
  }

footer {
  position: sticky;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: firebrick;
  }
```

```html
<nav>Navigation</nav>
<main>Content</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: check out my snippet please. Footer should NOT be shown in first look at website. after lots of scroll, we can find the footer. when you use `position: sticky;` for footer, it is going to be shown every where. as you can look it in your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Because the footer is inside `#main_content`, it only has as much z-index as the main content in relation to the navbar. So you need to set a z-index on the main content that is higher than the z-index of the navbar for the footer to cover the navbar. (Because you haven't shown the HTML, I'm only assuming the navbar is outside the main content container.)

The current high z-index of the footer only operates in relation to the nearest positioned parent element, which is presumably the `#main_content` container.

Another complication, though, is that you want the contents of `main_content` to go under the navbar, so that presents another problem. So my advice would be to place the footer *outside* `main_content` and give it a higher z-index than the navbar. You can't have the footer covering the navbar if it's inside the main content and you want the rest of the main content to sit under the navbar.

Comment: I Edited my Question and Uploaded Full HTML and CSS. footer should be in the `scrollable_content` to be scrollable after `main content` (I said wrong before). how can I bring it out of `scrollable_content` and expect it to still be scrollable?

Comment: As I said, `scrollable_content` has a z-index of 9. *Nothing inside that can have a higher z-index that 9* in relation to elements outside that container. You could put a z-index of a million on the footer and it would still just have a z-index of 9 as far as the navbar is concerned. Your **only** option is to put the footer outside `scrollable_content` and give it a higher z-index than the navbar.