# Scoped style to the parent of router-view | Vue 3 CLI

Tags: css, vue.js, scope, vuejs3, vue-router

I need to use a specific style to **`parent`** of `<router-view />`, when a specific page requested; Otherwise, I need a default style.

All of my pages have `navbar` and `footer` so I put them in `App.vue`.

But, for a great `User Experience`, I need to put my `<router-view />` into another element called `article#scrollable_content`.

When you visit the main page (`/` page | `HomeView.vue` view), this element is hidden in bottom of page and you only see a picture + the `navbar`. When you scroll down, the `#scrollable_content` element will cover that picture. (More details and `snippet` codes in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76548156/15198552))

But, this element must **NOT** be hidden when you request / visit another page (ex. `/foo` page | `FooView.vue` view) and It gonna start from top of the page normally (`top: 0;`)

The problem is here, `#scrollable_content` is in `App.vue` file and it runs for every request. in views, `scoped` styles will not effect `#scrollable_content`; And other styles, will effect **ALL** requests (not **ONLY** the same request).

**NOTE**: I cannot move `#scrollable_content` into every view because my `footer` is in this element and I'm not going to copy `footer` in every view.

Any idea to fix this problem?